# A reference to the static contex similar to class self-reference `this`, frequent use of `this` as a coding style

Tags: java, reference, static, this

I've consistently used a class self-reference `this` whether or not it is mandatory. I believe it helps the code readability as people who read it don't have to figure out on their own what scope the variable belongs to.

I would like to work similar with the static scope: precede all references to the static context with a `static` keyword and so make the code a bit more self-explanatory.

Java, however, doesn't like it. I know I could technically use simply the class name, but this looks pretty ugly, especially when a class has got a lengthy name. I could also precede the names of static methods and attributes with a special prefix, but I wouldn't like to be considered a paranoiac.

Would you guys consider any of this a good OOP style? Or should I just completely forget about anything vide supra and let javac do all the scope-binding?

Comment: "Good OOP style" has nothing to do with it. I'd find it irritating. Properly-sized methods should leave very little to the imagination when it comes to *either* instance or class methods.

Comment: To sum up: I guess it's rather non-mainstream to use any of this. For complex projects an IDE should help to see what's going on and for the simpler code it should be fairly straightforward to resolve the scope in head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some conventions that prefix all uses of member fields (or even methods) with `this`. There are also conventions for prefixing variable or class names (the infamous Hungarian notation). For example, official Android code style guidelines require prefixing private member field names with `m-` (such as `private int mSize`) and private static with `s-`.

Personally, I hate both of these conventions, because they just clutter the already quite verbose Java code. Modern IDEs provide some means of visual differentiation. For example in Eclipse, local variables are in standard black font, whereas fields are in blue. Static methods or fields are in italics.

They also provide great ways how to navigate through the source code. Ctrl+clicking on name of a variable/method/type takes you right to its declaration. There are outline views. Eclipse even displays a tooltip with information about such thing just if you hover your mouse over it.

Yes, somebody might put the argument that you sometimes do not read code in the IDE, but in a simple text editor. I sometimes do that too for a quick look over the code, but honestly, whenever I want to do some serious coding, not using an IDE is just a masochism.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to reconsider using Eclipse or Netbeans. Although it constantly makes me annoyed to see underlined in red things I've not finished typing yet. And when I forget in the exam how to write the main method, cause IDE _has always done it for me_. I have sometimes got an impression IDEs have evicted a lot of the good programming practice, but maybe for the sake of development speed.

Comment: And thanks for mentioning Hungarian notation in android code style guidlines!

Answer (score 3):

Most Java programmers expect to see the `this` keyword only where there is an ambiguity to be resolved. Applying it liberally as you propose is likely to make others unnecessarily suspicious. For statics, I guess you can use some Hungarian-esque notation if that's your bag, but it's also not that difficult to spot them when reviewing code (unless it's horribly monolithic or something).

Comment: I'm not really sure if Hungarian notation is compliant with cammelCase, I have only seen it used by nomen omen (if you like latin terms ;)) Eastern European C++ programmers, which makes it both, I guess far away from Java and far away from mainstream.

Comment: The beauty of programming is that you can have Hungarian camels if you wish!  `private static _sOurCamel = new Camel()`  But yes, Hungarian notation is about as rare as liberal use of `this` in (Western?) Java :)

Comment: @pectin Bear in mind there are two types of Hungarian notation.

Comment: After saying all that, I'm looking through some GWT sample code and...they use `this` all over the place inside classes.  Conclusion: do what you like - if it's good enough for Google...

Answer (score 3):

Don't try this at work:

```
public class Foo
{
    private static class This extends Foo{}

    static int x;
    static void f(int x){}

    void test()
    {
        This.f(This.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, it's quite deep java OOP.

Comment: why not just do `Foo.f(Foo.x)`?

Comment: @newacct supposedly the name of `Foo` is very long

Comment: also, it would not be uniform across different classes. The preceding _keyword_ should immediately trigger off a proper association.

Answer (score 2):

Most IDE's can very quickly locate the source of the variable referenced. It is nowadays therefore considered merely distracting to add extra hints as to their scope etc.

In summary, please do not use `this` unnecessarily, and please abandon all of your efforts to hold the hands of the programmers' who come after you, apart from, obviously, *choosing good names, writing good code and adding good comments*.

Comment: I actually use a very simple text editor (gedit), as I dislike when my machine consumes too much resources on running a JVM in background, and I've found explicit self-referencing to speed up code writing. However, I wouldn't like to irritate anybody who reads my code after me, so I would rather follow the most common practice. If using `this` has got a bad PR, I think I would just abandon it.

Comment: @picrin - I'm sorry for your disability :) - you should either make your boss get a decent computer for you or save up for one.

Comment: Well, there are still a few programming celebrities using even more low-level things as vi or emacs, so I guess using a lightweight IDE might be in some cases just a matter of taste.

Comment: Leaving aside the IDE vs text editor debate, I think a good programmer shouldn't go around assigning things to variables without first understanding what they are doing, and so discovering what type, scope and accessibility a variable has should be part of that process.

Comment: @picrin I don't see how vi or Emacs are " lower level" than gedit, it's quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all the static methods on a static inner class with a simple naming scheme.  For example:

```
public class Myclass {

    public void instanceMethod() {
        Static.doThing();
    }


    public static class Static {
        public static void doThing() {
            //blah
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is pure evil. :)

Comment: @Natix Meh.  You won't find me doing it, but I'm not into code snobbery either.  If people like it, then power to them.

Comment: This is a nice solution! But if it's not widely used people would probably find it pretty odd.

Comment: @picrin I doubt anybody has actually used such pattern. Not recommended, honestly.

Comment: Yeap, I think I'll just keep my classes neat and practice scope-binding in head. Thanks for a non-standard idea though!